# Google script: Create and publicly share a folder within existing parent

Tags: google-apps-script, directory, parent, sharing, subdirectory

So I'd like to create and (*publicly*) share a new folder within an existing parent.

Eg: \September 2013\[new folder here]

Sure, you could:

1. Use createFolder, to create a folder in root
2. Use addToFolder, to copy newly created folder into a given parent
3. Use removeFromFolder, to remove the folder from root

But then, publicly sharing that folder is not possible!

Indeed, if you try using: setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);

You will get: "TypeError: Cannot find function setSharing in object Folder."

That's right, the above DriveApp function seems to only work with folders made with DriveApp.createFolder.

And of course, there is no way to simply:

1. Use DriveApp.createFolder, to create a folder in root
2. Use setSharing, to publicly share the newly created folder
3. Move the new folder to the desired sub-folder

... as there is no move method!

Has anyone found a solution to such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of DocsList and DriveApp can be useful.

```
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function main() {
  var parentFolder = DocsList.getFolder('September 2013');
  var idNewFolder = parentFolder.createFolder('New Folder').getId();
  var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(idNewFolder);
  newFolder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted - I'd love to hear from whoever did that, with an explanation we can all learn from. Personally, I like this AND @sergeinsas answer: +1 to both!

Comment: @Mogsdad I didn't downvote it, but it may have been because DocsList has been 'replaced' with Drive app with bugfixes etc (I assume they left DocsList there so as not to completely break older scripts.) See this [bug reply](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2115#c43) and [Blog announcement](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/new-apps-script-features-at-google.html). My guess is that DocsList will be deprecated eventually, so best to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use 2 services, driveApp has all you need already build in

You simply forgot that you can create a folder from another one, not only from root... so you don't need to move anything.

example :

```
function createSharedFolder() {
  var parent = DriveApp.createFolder('testFolder');
  var child = parent.createFolder('child');
  child.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
}
```

To solve these simple questions think about making use of the autocomplete, see screen capture below :

[image]

if your parent folder already exist or if your not sure about it, here is a function that handles all use cases : (+ a function to test the function)

```
function test(){
 createSharedSubFolder('Testparent','Testchild2');
}

function createSharedSubFolder(parent,child) { // folder names as string parameters
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var exist = false
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    if(folder.getName()==parent){exist = true ; var folderId = folder.getId() ; break};// find the existing folder
 }
  if(exist){
  var child = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFolder(child).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
  }else{
  var childFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(parent).createFolder(child);
  childFolder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Since parent folder already exists, there is a direct way to find it through DriveApp?

Comment: DriveApp lacks the functionality getFolder(path), which is why I prefer to use DocsList here.

Comment: indeed ... it seems that Googlers like iterators !, that said iterators are really nice too and code remains short enough so it's not so bad at all.

Comment: Usually there is always more than one way to solve a problem, iterators is another option, but DocsList, can do so directly.